# Solving for unkown ratios while being given various sums of the unkowns

Tags: data-analysis

Setup/Scenario:

So let's suppose you have 4 types of apples:
red, blue, yellow, and green

When present, each color apple will always be present in a proportionally consistent manner to other colored apples. Different apples will appear in different piles and you know which piles are limited to specific colors of apples.

R:B:Y:G being
4:2:0:1 for example

Pile 1: 8R, 4B, 0Y, 2G

Pile 2: 16R, 8B, 4G

Pile 3: 4R, 0Y, 1G

Pile 4: 16R, 8B

Pile 5: 8B, 2G

Pile 6: 8R, 0Y

Pile 7: 4R

Problem:

You are forced to wear glasses that make you see in greyscale, and can't discern the colors of the apples. The only information you have is:

Pile 1: 14 Total, pile contains RBYG

Pile 2: 28 Total, pile contains RBG

Pile 3: 5 Total, pile contains RYG

Pile 4: 24 Total, pile contains RB

Pile 5: 10 Total, pile contains BG

Pile 6: 8 Total, pile contains RY

Pile 7: 4 Total, pile contains R

Are there any ways to find the master ratio of 4:2:0:1 from the information you're given?

I'd also like to note that fractions of apples are fair play, they can exist in a pile.

Extra information on the question for the curious:

-If this isn't possible I would still find value in an answer that only solves for certain colors of apples, ie if only part of the master ratio can be solved I would still deem this information useful.

-General rules would be helpful if you happen to realize any. For example, if (# of piles) must be > (# of apple colors)

-If there's some sort of tweak necessary to the given information that doesn't simply add more piles of apples with individual colors, then I would also be interested.

-I would like to aim to limit the number of individual-colored-apple piles to 1 if possible, if switching pile 7's color gives a solution I would be interested.

Comment: It seems like Y is not included in any!

Comment: The definition is not complete - why you can't have 4 B or 4 G?

Comment: Check divisibility by 7, 5 or 3.

Comment: you are saying that pile 6 contains Red and Yellow, but it has no yellow!

Comment: To address the no Y's being present, this is a possible scenario I'm considering. If it is present, it will be in the pre-determined piles, but it does not have to be present, does that cause a problem?

@Moti for which piles are you asking about?

Comment: File 7 could be B or G as well... same with 6. You may resolve any combination of at least 2 colors - you can not find a color by itself or combinations of RB or BG